# Java boolean values not equal but equal?

Tags: java, boolean

I'm learning java from a website called udacity and a question I just got asked was "done is a boolean value. What is the value of !!done?" I didn't really understand it but after a while of guessing I got the correct answer of "done." Could someone explain this to me? Isn't ! supposed to mean "not equal"? How can value1 be equal to value2 which is supposed to be "not equal" to value1?

Comment: As you can see, there are two exclamation marks, so the value is switched two times. So, assuming done is true: !done equals not true which is false; !!done equals not not true which is not false which is true.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks the minimal understanding of the subject and does not show any research effort

Comment: oh, and I would really love to see such a brave will to answer on serious questions which describe a problem that is of higher complexity than the usage of an operator ;)

Comment: Yeah sorry if I offended anyone with my question but it's just that the forums for the website were down so that's why I came here. I realise now it was a simple mistake as I didn't properly pay attention to the fact that there were two exclamation marks instead of just the one.

Answer (score 4):

this goes back to boolean algebra, If you say

```
true = true   
false = false
```

then

```
not true = false
not false = true
```

so that means

```
not (not true)  = not false = true 
not (not false) = not true  = false
```

which means !!done = done

you can write "not" as "!"

```
!true  = false
!false = true
```

which means

```
!!true  = !false = true
!!false = !true = false
```

so if done is a boolean: true or false, when its put in !!done it will always be done. for example:

```
boolean done = true;
```

`!!done`  this will always be its initial value which is `true`

Answer (score 1):

! is the negation operator in java, so !! done, is not not done, is the same as done.  It is simply a double negative

Answer (score 0):

The operator `!` negates a boolean value. This means:

```
!!x == x

!!true = true
!!false = false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. As I mentioned above I guess I just wasn't paying enough attention and didn't think about the fact that there were two exclamation marks instead of one. Thanks for helping guys :)